# How to find unused variables in proceadure or package in oracle?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How to find the UNUSED variables in oracle packages or procedures

```
 for example:-

 I am declaring 100 variables in procedure, among those i used 70 variables in procedure body. I want the unused variables(100-70)=30.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get that information using PL/Scope and/or compiler warnings.

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSCOPE_SETTINGS='IDENTIFIERS:ALL';
```

(OR)

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS='ENABLE:ALL';
```

See this related Posts

[Oracle PL/SQL: How to find unused variables in a long package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868567/oracle-pl-sql-how-to-find-unused-variables-in-a-long-package)

[How to find Unused variables in procedure,function or package](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2571725?start=0&tstart=0)